# Unknown provider: sumByKeyFilterProvider <- sumByKeyFilter

Tags: angularjs

I have a custom filter, taken from here: https://gist.github.com/Cacodaimon/7309268. I call it sumByKey, it's in a file called `sumByKey.filter.js`. It's been working fine.
I tried to write three more custom filters.

`totalSetupTime.filter.js`:

```
angular.module("core", [])
    .filter('totalSetupTime', function () {
        return function (order, options) {
            if (typeof (order) === 'undefined' || typeof (options) === 'undefined') {
                return 0;
            }

            var toReturn = 0;
            angular.forEach(order.Operations, function (obj, objKey) {
                toReturn += options.SetupTime;
            });
            return toReturn;
        };
    });
```

`runTimePlusSetup.filter.js`:

```
angular.module("core", [])
    .filter('runTimePlusSetup', function () {
        return function (order, options) {
            if (typeof (order) === 'undefined' || typeof (options) === 'undefined') {
                return 0;
            }

            totalRunTimeMinutes = 0;
            $.each(order.Operations, function (idx, elem) {
                totalRunTimeMinutes += elem.RunTimeMinutesPerPiece;
            });
            return $filter('totalSetupTime')(order, options) + order.Pieces * totalRunTimeMinutes / 60.0;
        };
    });
```

`runTimePlusSetupPlusEfficiency.filter.js`:

```
angular.module("core", [])
    .filter('runTimePlusSetupPlusEfficiency', function () {
        return function (order, options) {
            if (typeof (order) === 'undefined' || typeof (options) === 'undefined') {
                return 0;
            }

            return $filter('runTimePlusSetup')(order, options) * 2.0;
        };
    });
```

that's totalSetupTime, in a file of course called `totalSetupTime.filter.js`. If I include this file, my main page throws me an error; `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: sumByKeyFilterProvider <- sumByKeyFilter`. I don't think the problem is actually the sumByKey filter, because that's been working fine, but if I take out all 3 (and it must be all 3) of my new custom filters, it goes back to working as intended. The component I'm getting all the sumByKey errors on doesn't use any of these new filters at all, so I don't understand how they're throwing off angular. The component that does use them throws `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: totalSetupTimeFilterProvider <- totalSetupTimeFilter`. 
Am I just destroying all of angular's filtering ability? how can I get my custom filters working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the second and third filter should be:

```
angular.module("core")
    .filter('runTimePlusSetup', function () {
```

&

```
angular.module("core")
    .filter('runTimePlusSetupPlusEfficiency', function () {
```

The syntax you use creates new module all the time :

```
angular.module("core", [])
    .filter('runTimePlusSetup', function () {
```

Reference : Check the official docs @ https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Check the section " Creation vs Retrieval"